# Android softkeyboard error message

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

After I imported the softkeyboard sample I got an error message when I opened input.xml

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details
```

Error:

```
Thu Jul 19 00:03:38 CST 2012 com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView failed to instantiate.
...
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x10d000e type #0x3 is not valid
    at android.content.res.Resources.getBoolean(Resources.java:679)
    at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.<init>(KeyboardView.java:363)
    at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.<init>(KeyboardView.java:270)
    at com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView.<init>(LatinKeyboardView.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:402)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:166)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:205)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:133)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:296)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:279)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:318)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1640)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1391)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1165)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:679)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setActivePage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.setActivePage(FormEditor.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:300)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:837)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:889)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4687)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:962)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3071)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:2996)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2978)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2974)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2933)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2924)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:655)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.OpenAndExpand.run(OpenAndExpand.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$3.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: Same issue. I suppose they have simply not implemented the Software Keyboard in ADT.

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem came when some resource is missing just copy the resource id from log cat and search in r.java file and place that resource in drawable folder.

May it help you.

AndroidLover

Answer (score 0):

Try this in manifext file

```
<service
    android:name="SoftKeyboard"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether all the **resources ids** in the `LatinKeyboardView` belong to the layout that you have set in the `setContent()`.

Answer (score 0):

On which device or emulator you are trying to run this example, it seems that this resource is not present in that environment.
Check for which API Level is this example written and then try to run on a device or emulator of same or higher API level.

Answer (score 0):

Open your R.java and search for this "0x10d000e" id. You ll get a name that which resource is not available at the run time. So, you can exactly figure out which resource is missing.

This problem mainly comes when you are using fragments.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Compile it with correct API level.

Answer (score 0):

The resource ID does not make sense for the android, You should make correct ID and then compile it by changing the API level.
 May it helps

Answer (score 0):

hello i have face the same issue and i resolvet it by below steps.....

please download https://gitorious.org/replicant/development/source/7b53e3937797ee1eea71c6291bdcd58cb9dedf7a:samples/SoftKeyboard

and copy SoftKeyboard.java and candidateview.java file and and edite services in your manifest file it will work